# create $vectorSearch index in mongodb mongosh terminal

Tags: mongodb, vector-search, semantic-search

I want to create $vectorSearch index to use mongodb semantic search. I found some official documents that describes how to make it through mongodb Altas cloud dashboard. But I need to make it on my localhost mongodb with a command in monogsh terminal. How can I do that?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Notice that the specific product title is "Atlas Vector Search", not "MongoDB Vector Search".  I'm pretty sure the Atlas folks have additional processes running aside from the mongod node to enable Atlas Search and Atlas Vector Search.